# VPN connecting, but not

Tags: openvpn

I've recently upgraded to 17.10, and setting up the VPN. When I connect, it all seems to work okay, even the VPN website (StrongVPN) say's I've connected. But when I check my IP address it is the same as when I'm not connected to the VPN.

Any help will be appreciated.
Cheers
Alan

Comment: Please add the result of `route`

Comment: Is your VPN connection `tun` or `tap`?